# C# : Generate a document and print it?

Tags: c#, printing

There is a huge number of questions about printing, but no one of them is exactly what I want, here is my situation.

**What I have :**
I have 2 textBoxes, and one pictureBox (textBox1, textBox2, and pictureBox1), and a button (print).

[image]

**What I want :**
I want to reorganise the data entered text, with the picture, like this :

[image]

And then print them directly, or by showing a printDialog to choose the printer. all this by pressing one button.

**What I know till now :**
I know that I need to use printDocument and printDialog but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to print something, you must specify coordinates for each object that you want it to be on the page. 
There is some "automatic" way in .NET 4 if I'm not mistaken, that allows you to print your application window, but it is very rigid and I do NOT reccomend it.

Have a look at this [.pdf](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/74/04705328/DOWNLOAD/532874_both02_p2.pdf). Examples are VB.NET but it's the same sh*...
It covers all your needs for printing in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer, I'll check the PDF and let you know if it gets the task done!

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this example from MSDN on printDialog.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try this link, and try the example! Thanks again.